# is it possible to do authorization using SAML

Tags: php, saml-2.0

Currently i am using simplesamlphp and we have successfully implemented SSO, in which SAML request is sending through HTTP-REDIRECT and getting response through HTTP-POST.

Here my doubts are:

Can i send the authentication details(username&password) using HTTP-POST?

Is the simplesamlphp only for authentication or can i use for authorization purpose like oath for Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

When you authenticate with simplesamlPHP, you get a SAML token which contains attributes, These attributes are what are used for authorisation. They can be derived from "a storage of users, a database, a LDAP or a radius interface".

Username can definitely be an attribute. However, password shouldn't be for security reasons.

In terms of authentication, it supports OpenID. For OAuth, I suspect you would have to roll your own authentication module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For example if i got any attribute which is unique to each user(something like user_id) in authentication response. By using this unique key can i build a SAML request and send it to IDP and get additional details like user's posts, user's comments by using simplesamlphp (or) simplesamlphp is only for authenticating users...?

Comment: The normal pattern for an STS is that you configure all the attributes you require and they are all sent in the SAML token.